# How to add a layer with multiply blend mode on image when hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, blend

I want something like this when hover: from the first image to the second image. The effects are: **greyscale** and **blur** original image + **a multiply layer on top.**

[image: From this]

[image: to this]

Right now I'm using the change to another image trick to do this but it's inconvenient. Here's  my code so far:

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.showtext + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 113px;
  top: 113px;
color: white; 
 text-decoration:underline;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.showtext:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item">
       <h3>Plython album</h3>
       <span class="category">identity</span>

       <div class="imgwrapper">
       <img  class="showtext" src="images/thumb_item08.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/thumb_item08a.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/thumb_item08.png';" />
       <div id="view">view</div></div>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
    </a>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you find this code helpful.

[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/vxvf28jx/7/)

You need to adding a container to your image and triggered the hovering on it.

```css
.img-con {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5%;
  background: rgba(209, 19, 15, 0);
  transition: ease .1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease .1s;
  -moz-transition: ease .1s;
  -ms-transition: ease .1s;
  -o-transition: ease .1s;
}
.img-con > img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transition: ease .1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease .1s;
  -moz-transition: ease .1s;
  -ms-transition: ease .1s;
  -o-transition: ease .1s;
}
.img-con:hover {
  background: rgba(209, 19, 15, 0.75);
}
.img-con:hover > img {
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px) contrast(200%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px) contrast(200%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-con">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzzFU.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes it works perfectly! thank u

Comment: I just realized that the red layer is not multiply. When I use background-image and background-blend-mode: multiply; it turns multiply, but in your code, the image link is in the HTML so I can't  figure out how to make it multiply, is there a way? Thanks

Comment: I figured it out by using mix-blend-mode, it works as I want now.